# Future safe jobs in area of graphic design

Tags: business, education

I've been playing with graphic design for years but never serious. Right now I have the time and resources to go deeper and become really good in a specific area of GD.

With things changing so fast in the GD world I'm wondering with area or direction in GD is a safe bet for the future.

With so much competition and automation certain current jobs might not be there in the future but what area of GD would be a good bet to start learning and investing time in?

Comment: Welcome to GraphicDesign.SE!

Comment: This is my opinion, but by getting a FIRM grasp on the fundamentals of graphic design and really honing your craft and your taste level (practice everything, immerse yourself in design everywhere you can, absorb as much as possible), you will be better able to adapt to many different areas in the graphic design field. Some of my most skilled friends have bounced around from a variety of design-related disciplines with ease, because at the end of the day they monster designers.

Comment: Voting to close as we can't predict the future.

Comment: Nothing is safe, most jobs we do have to today didnt even exist a 30 years ago

Comment: Any job that is related to technology nowadays is a moving target. There is no way to predict what we will create 5 years from now (tactile interfaces?). The best you can do is to get a solid foundation on the basic laws of design. They do exist and stay the same independently of the application. You should also train yourself on  flexibility and adaptability.

Answer (score 2):

Without being strictly graphic design related, I think User experience is one of the fields that are growing fast and are more lucrative than straight up GD. There are tons of templates out there but they are useless if you can't navigate the content properly. UI can be applied to websites, apps, wearable, the Internet of things, and more.

Also, I would probably look into getting some 3D modeling skills with 3D printing being right at our door and likely a whole revolution in the manufacturing world.

"Future safe" doesn't always depend on the nature of the job though but also on the persistence/willingness of the employee to update their skills and stay on top.

Comment: 3D printing has been hip for the last 10 years (Been around much earlier) and hasnt realy moved anywhere. Its not like the same 3d modeling could not be used in cnc milling. And that you could have done for 40 odd years. Nothing new here.

Comment: @joojaa I respectfully disagree. 3D printers became accessible price-wise just a handful of years ago, allowing people to buy them and use them at home. Some really innovative design prototypes for all kinds of things (accessibility tools, figurines, toys, utensils) are now being printed on personal 3D printers. I don't think it's that bad a suggestion.

Comment: I didn't say its a bad advice its just not graphics design related. Have you ever used a off the shelf 3d printer? My uni has 20 printers free for use, materials included.  To get use rights all you need to show up for the weekly training for users to get into 3d printing. Its full of graphics artists, business people and always one or 2 engineers. The non engineers are always really excited until they realize that printing something the size of a small remote takes 12-20 hours. Plus you need to clean it up manually for another 3 hours. The CNC shop 1-2 hours and its polished, ready to go.

Comment: @joojaa Yep! Not my own printer, but we have friends who have let us come over and play with theirs. It's getting popular among game artists (which is my industry). My point is it's getting easier and more accessible every year, and I think having the ability to model something out for a prototype is an excellent skill to have. My friends who spend all day modeling trees and characters for work come home and print pretty rad side projects. I can think of a few times it would have come in handy when I was working in print design and we had to mock up some crazy press-kit package designs.